# Call servlet from jsp and use if

Tags: jsp, servlets, tomcat6

Been trying to find a solution for this for a while , I have a form in a html file

```
      <form id="form" name="form" method="post" ACTION="First_Q.jsp" >
```

the current from as shown above when submitted simply goes to a jsp...

However I have a form servlet which i want to pass the form data to where an IF will be performed to decide if the user is returning or not . I've tried changing ACTION numerous times both to Game.FormServlet and Game/FormServlet as shown in other examples but this doesn't work.

The Game folder is placed with other servlets in the src folder .

Basically I want to know 1.how to pass the form data to the servlet 2.How to program the servlet to take the result of the if statement and based on that move to another jsp..

setting setting the
           The_Quiz.RegistrationServlet.java

as suggested in one of the answers throws the following error

gives me the error

cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'servlet-path'. One of '{"http:// java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":servlet-class, "java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":jsp-file}' is expected.

Answer (score 1):

A servlet must be declared and mapped to an URL pattern in the web.xml file of your webapp.

```
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>SomeUniqueName</servlet-name>
     <servlet-path>the.fully.qualified.name.of.the.ServletClass</servlet-path>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>SomeUniqueName</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/foobar</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Once this is done, you can use the chosen URL to invoke the servlet:

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/foobar" >
```

Comment: Cool , thank you , tried a few different approaches and they didnt work , I'll do this now

Comment: setting the <servlet-path>The_Quiz.RegistrationServlet.java</servlet-path>

Comment: gives me the error cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'servlet-path'. One of '{"http://
 java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":servlet-class, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":jsp-file}' is expected.

Answer (score 1):

Form actions map to URLs, not classes. URLs map to classes via `web.xml` or annotations.

Form data is available in the request via the [`getParameter(String)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29).

Once you have the data you can act on it as you see fit, and use a [`RequestDispatcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) to forward to the appropriate JSP:

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
RequestDispatcher rd = context.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/result.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Any servlet/JSP tutorial will provide you with further information; I'd recommend reading one before proceeding much further–you'll save yourself a lot of time. Depending on your app container you might want to take advantage of the new annotations as well.

Answer (score -1):

I added a doPost and then cleaned the solution which solved the problem